# MySQL Logical Operators in a field with text and integers

Tags: mysql, logical-operators

I have a table that looks like:

```
ATTRIBUTE1 | ATTRIBUTE2
weight: 190| height: 175
ctr: 400   | dmd: 19
```

Is it possible to do comparative operations on these fields?

Like, if I wanted to find everyone with a weight less than 200, what would the syntax look like for that? I figure the query would look like the following, if there were no text in the field:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE attribute1 < '200'
```

But since the field has the defining text "weight:", I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Is Attribute1 a fieldname?  Is "weight:190 ctr:400" field value? Or Is "weight:190" fieldvalue?

Comment: `Attribute1` and `attribute2` are the column names. `weight: 190` is a field value, as is `ctr: 400`

Comment: Yes this can be achieved using a combination of MySQL string functions but this will result in slow queries. Consider revising your database structure.

Comment: Thanks Salman, I think that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where cast(substring(ATTRIBUTE1, instr(ATTRIBUTE1, ': ')+1 ) as unsigned) <200
```

alternative:

```
where cast(replace(Field_2, 'weight: ', '') as unsigned) > 180
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(attribute1, INSTR(attribute, ': ') AS SIGNED)
```

because the value contains the string in the beginning.

Basically you do like this:

Find the index of ': ' and use it as a substring for the value (to skip everything until the actual number). Then you cast it to an Int

(maybe you need to add a +1 to INSTR. I'm not sure since i don't have a mysql client right here

Comment: (i) needs one extra bracket (ii) needs + 2, not + 1

Comment: Thanks for explaining, makes a bit more sense now.